# image uploading issue using httpurlconnection class

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

i am using this code for uploading image using httpurlconnection class.in this code image uploaded successfully and i m getting path of uploaded image in response but when i try to open image path in browser, it will say image contain error

```
public class JSONParser {

private static JSONObject jobj = null;
private final String SERVER_PATH = "server url";

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String murl, Utils.method m, Map<String, String> parmas, String Token, String filepath, String filefield, String filemimetype){
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String urlTo = SERVER_PATH + murl;

    String result = "";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlTo);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        if (m.equals(Utils.method.POST)) {
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } else if (m.equals(Utils.method.GET)){
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        /*connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");*/
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        if (Token != null){
            connection.addRequestProperty("token", Token);
        }
          if (m.equals(Utils.method.POST)) {
            outputStream = new        DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        }
        if (filepath != null) {
            String[] q = filepath.split("/");
            int idx = q.length - 1;
            File file = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + filemimetype + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        }
//            outputStream.writeBytes(getQuery(parmas));
        if (m.equals(Utils.method.POST)) {
            if (!parmas.isEmpty()) {
                Iterator<String> keys = parmas.keySet().iterator();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    String value = parmas.get(key);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(value);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                }
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            }
        }

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        System.out.println("Response :"+result);
        jobj = new JSONObject(result);
        inputStream.close();
        if (m.equals(Utils.method.POST)) {
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        connection.disconnect();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jobj;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
  }
```

Comment: Download the image and compare with original. Start with comparing file sizes.

Comment: `outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);`. That should be `outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);`

Comment: still it is not working

Comment: You are not serious. If you want help then supply the requested information.

Comment: i have tried what u said earlier but still my image is null at API side. i m working on client app so they have directly provided API so i have no information about php code

Comment: `my image is null at API side` What do you mean by that? I asked for a file size.

Comment: `so they have directly provided API`. Maybe you should show that here?

Comment: Bitmap is not passed in API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123324/discussion-between-sagar-and-greenapps).

Comment: i have no access to php code so i can't give you a code

Comment: I did not ask for the code but for the API. As you said they provided the API to you. And you are still not providing file sizes and explaining that null.

Comment: file size is 0 at server side